# confirm box styling

Tags: javascript

I want to style the confirm box generated by JavaScript. I want the background color of the box to be green and replace `ok/cancel` with `yes/no`. Do you know how to do this ?

Answer (score 10):

You can't style a `confirm();` alert -- this is generic to the browser. Instead, look into alternatives such as [boxy for jQuery](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/):

[image: boxy for jQuery -- asking a question]

Of course, you can style this in CSS until your heart melts. ;-)

Comment: Hi gary .. i am new to jquery and have hardly used it... can u please provide me with the code which i can directly use... it will be of great help to me ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the jQuery dialog box. Check this out [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)