# How to set font color or background color to javascript confim box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to apply background color to `javascript` conform dialog or also can be done by applying font color to some text.

I've tried following code:

```
confirm('You Have Deviated Sequence of extra subjects. \n\nAre you sure you want to replace ' + document.write(MySubjectNo.bold()) + ' with "' + replacingSubject.big() + '"?');
```

`document.write(MySubjectNo.bold())`

is also not working.

Comment: I don't think you can customize the javascript confirm dialog.

Comment: Not possible. The rendering of that dialog is down to the browser.

Comment: You can't, see post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498988/confirm-box-styling][1] for a solution


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498988/confirm-box-styling

Answer (score 3):

You can't, this is a native control from the browser and this can't be styled. You would have to rewrite an HTML version of that box with a similar behavior if you wish to style it in any way...

Answer (score 0):

You could use this jquery plugin [jquery-alerts](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/) to do the customization that you want. But, again, it's HTML and not the original browser dialog box.