# A very simple Alert and Confirm Box style with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the follow simple code for a confirm box

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Click the button to alert the hostname of the current URL.</p>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                confirm("Confirm!!!!");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

but my problem is I want with css to style the OK and Cancel button with a very simple way. I'm looking for a real simple solution.

Comment: You can't style them. You will have to use custom modal implementations.

Comment: If you're developing for mobile, I'd say keep the confirm and alert boxes. They work well and are styled in mobile browsers. If not for mobile, make your own DIV and style it.

Comment: It's impossible to style them. The only way to have a styled dialog is to simply have a normal `div` or other element that looks like a dialog

Comment: Finally i will use jQuery UI alert Box i think...Thanks for your answers guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alert` and `confirm` are built-in to JavaScript and STOP page execution until they are answered, which is what allows you to do:

```
if( confirm('do you want to see this?') ) {
    //show them.
}
```

Any confirm() solution that you work-up that can be styled won't be able to be included in an `if` statement.  If you want code to only execute when the `confirm` is clicked, then you need to make that code as a callback, which make the above code look more like this:

```
mySpecialConfirm('do you want to see this?', function() {
    //show them
} );
```

Then, you have to wire that function call into the "ok" button click on the confirm dialog that you create.  This means that it's inherently more complicated just from a coding standpoint not to mention the code that has to wire that up to an HTML form.  I would say that it's not worth it to re-invent the wheel and make your own modal.  This means that you need to choose jQuery and jQuery UI, or jQuery and Bootstrap, or Dojo Toolkit, etc., and then from there look for the solution that they have  for doing this, or use their modals.

Answer (score 5):

This question has been asked more:

- [How to style default confirm box with only css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185152/how-to-style-default-confirm-box-with-only-css)
- [confirm box styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498988/confirm-box-styling)

Answer; **you can NOT style the confirm()** function it's dialog box since it's browser generic.

---

You will have to search for alternatives like these:

- **jQuery Boxy**: [onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/)
- **jQuery Dialog**: [jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

You could also try to create your own dialog box. Which is not quite simple as you asked for. However, lot's of tutorials can be found:

- **Tutorial 1:** [www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1385](http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1385)
- **Tutorial 2:** [tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/)

(Sorry, as a beginner I'm not allowed to place more links)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't change the style of native pop up windows, but you can create your own with a bit of JavaScript trickery.

```
function promptWindow() {
  // Create template
  var box = document.createElement("div");
  var cancel = document.createElement("button");
  cancel.innerHTML = "Cancel";
  cancel.onclick = function() { document.body.removeChild(this.parentNode) }
  var text = document.createTextNode("Please enter a message!");
  var input = document.createElement("textarea");
  box.appendChild(text);
  box.appendChild(input);
  box.appendChild(cancel);

  // Style box
  box.style.position = "absolute"; 
  box.style.width = "400px";
  box.style.height = "300px";

  // Center box.
  box.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) -100;
  box.style.top = "100px";

  // Append box to body
  document.body.appendChild(box);

}
```

After calling `promptWindow` you have your own pop up box, which you are free to style!

Hope this helped!