# Is it possible to style OnClickClient event in Gridview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, modalpopup

I have this:

```
<ItemStyle Width="5" />
    <ItemTemplate >
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" 
          CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("requestTypeID")%>' 
          OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you really want to delete this request type?')"
        Text = "Delete" OnClick = "DeleteRequestType"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

When a user clicks the Delete button, they receive the following alert box:

***Are you sure you really want to delete this request type? some color?***

Is there a way to change the text color to blue?

Whether dialog box or not, my question is whether the text color can be changed.

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to be about styling an event (which makes no sense), but about styling a dialog box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [confirm box styling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498988/confirm-box-styling)

Comment: @pushkin, I a am using GridView and the link you reference does not address my concern.

Comment: "Whether dialog box or not, my question is whether the text color can be changed." My point was that you're not styling an event, but the text in a dialog box. Specifically, the text in a confirm dialog box. Why doesn't the link help? And what does the fact that it's a GridView have to do with anything? Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: You cannot directly modify any style of default alert/confirm message.But you can implement ajax popup just see [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Confirmation-Confirm-box-with-Yes-No-Buttons-Options-using-AJAX-Modal-Popup-Extender-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: @Neel,

Thank you very much. Most useful response.

I will like to give you credit for helping me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't style an alert window.  That is completely a function of the browser, outside the scope of styling.

You need to create a modal window if you want to customize colors or styling.